# Haskell How to convert Char to Word8

Tags: haskell, bytestring

I want to split `ByteString` to words like so:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS

main = do
    input <- BS.getLine
    let xs = BS.split ' ' input
```

But it appears that GHC can't convert a character literal to `Word8` by itself, so I got:

```
Couldn't match expected type `GHC.Word.Word8'
            with actual type `Char'
In the first argument of `BS.split', namely ' '
In the expression: BS.split ' ' input
```

Hoogle doesn't find anything with type signature of `Char -> Word8` and `Word.Word8 ' '` is invalid type constructor. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Don't use `ByteString` for text! Use [`Text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) instead.

Comment: @DanielWagner Why not? Is it faster than `ByteString`?

Comment: `Text` is unicode-friendly, so your strings will be strings in all countries. `ByteString` is for binary parsing, raw memory access, and can't handle anything other than ascii or latin1.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. That was for a programming-contest problem, so the range of possible encodings is limited to ascii.

Comment: You probably want to use import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B instead

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [Data.ByteString.Char8](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.9.2.1/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Char8.html) module allows you to treat `Word8` values in the bytestrings as `Char`. Just

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
```

then refer to e.g. [C.split](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.9.2.1/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#g:13). It's the same bytestring under the hood, but the `Char`-oriented functions are provided for convenient byte/ascii parsing.

Answer (score 17):

In case you *really* need Data.ByteString (not Data.ByteString.Char8), you could do what Data.ByteString itself does to convert between Word8 to Char:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Internal as BS (c2w, w2c)

main = do
    input <- BS.getLine
    let xs = BS.split (BS.c2w ' ') input 
    return ()
```

Answer (score 4):

People looking for a simple `Char -> Word8` with base library:

```
import Data.Word

charToWord8 :: Char -> Word8
charToWord8 = toEnum . fromEnum
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to directly address the question in the subject line, which led me here in the first place.

You can convert a single **`Char`** to a single **`Word8`** with **`fromIntegral.ord`**:

```
λ> import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
λ> import Data.Char(ord)

λ> BS.split (fromIntegral.ord $ 'd') $ BS.pack . map (fromIntegral.ord) $ "abcdef"

["abc","ef"]
```

Keep in mind that this conversion will be prone to **overflows** as demonstrated below.**You** have to assure that your **`Char`** fits in **8 bits**, if you do not want this to occur.

```
λ> 260 :: Word8

4
```

Of course, for your particular problem, it is preferable to use the [Data.ByteString.Char8](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html) module as already pointed out in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is the following:

```hs
charToWord8 :: Char -> Word8
charToWord8 = fromIntegral . ord
{-# INLINE charToWord8 #-}
```

where `ord :: Chat → Int` and the rest one can infer.