# OverloadedStrings for chars

Tags: haskell, bytestring

The hackage documentation for ByteString contains this [example](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.1/docs/Data-ByteString.html#g:13):

```
split :: Word8 -> ByteString -> [ByteString]
split '\n' "a\nb\nd\ne" == ["a","b","d","e"]
```

It's as if `'\n'` is converted to a `Word8`, but `LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings` seems only to work on strings, not chars. What extension to I need to include for the example code to work?

Comment: If I try that example, it results in an error. `Couldn't match expected type 'Word8' with actual type 'Char'
In the first argument of 'split', namely '\n'`

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623424/haskell-how-to-convert-char-to-word8

Answer (score 3):

`bytestring` supports a cheap and cheerful Latin1 view of the bytes. You can import [Data.ByteString.Char8](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.9.2.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html) to get that view.